# Getting data as JSON from a PHP file on the server

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am using `AJAX` call to request the `PHP` file from the server. The `PHP` file is holding some objects. `JSON.parse()` is being used to convert the result into a `JavaScript` object. So the problem is after running the program I see the following error in the browser console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at XMLHttpRequest.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange (index.php:15)
```

I have no idea why the program is not working, although my Apache server, and PHP are running fine.
The program I am working on:

index.php:

```
    <p id="demo"></p>

<script>

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myObj.name;
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "demo_file.php", true);
xmlhttp.send();

</script>
```

demo_file.php:

```
    <?php
$myObj->name = "John";
$myObj->age = 30;
$myObj->city = "New York";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have a warning that $myObj is not initialized:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/json');
$myObj = new stdClass; 
$myObj->name = "John";
$myObj->age = 30;
$myObj->city = "New York";
echo json_encode($myObj);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I want to hug you!

Answer (score 4):

You can build json in php with [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function:

```
<?php

$myObj = new stdClass(); 
$myObj->name = "John";
$myObj->age = 30;
$myObj->city = "New York";

echo json_encode($myObj);
```

Comment: Mohammad Hamedani, thnaks for your answer. I already know that. But I want to make XMLHTTP request to get data from the file. In this case, PHP file sits in the server and Javascript is a client program- thats exactly what I am trying to do in my program, and its not working. Can you help me with that?

Comment: You ever figure out the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is asked 1 year ago but still not answered correctly if I am right. I was facing same issue and solved it by providing correct path to file.

**Solution:** If your client code and server code are in the same folder, logically there is no need to give path of the root folder, but in this case you have provide root folder. For example: if you client.php and demo_file.php files are in the same folder **Pages**
then the solution will be:

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myObj.name;
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "Pages/demo_file.php", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```